# "GetAuthorizationGroups" throws exception when reading groups for user from Active Directory

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm trying to find groups via `GetAuthorizationGroups`, and it's sort of working in that I can get an IEnumerable back, but most of the items I get back throw an exception when I try to read them:

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices.COMException:
The specified directory service attribute or value does not exist.
```

If you plug in your own domain, container, and username, you should get a list of their groups:

Powershell:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices")
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.DirectoryServices.ActiveDirectory")

$username = "a-user-such-as-yourself"

$principalContext = new-object -TypeName System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.PrincipalContext "Domain", "yourADdomain.com", "OU=whatever,OU=andever,DC=yourADdomain,DC=com"

$principal = [System.DirectoryServices.AccountManagement.UserPrincipal]::FindByIdentity($principalContext, $username)

$groups = $principal.GetAuthorizationGroups()
Write-Output $groups
```

If I ignore all the exceptions, it successfully returns the groups "Everyone", "Authenticated Users", and a couple more, but throws an exception on others.

*If I run this as a Domain Admin it works fine, returning all groups without any exceptions.*

*So I'm assuming that the user running this needs some sort of permission in Active Directory. But which one?*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Our wonderful sysadmin got this working by restoring some default permissions that were absent in our AD for complicated reasons. We were missing READ permissions to `Authenticated Users` on the standard `Users` container in Active Directory.

Comment: Being unable to read `Authenticated Users` sounds like there were plenty of other problems. Care to elaborate at a high level? Curious